# How to run an interactive console program like htop directly on tty?

Tags: linux, pipe, tty

i did make an interesting discovery on my raspberry pi. if I run the following as root:

```
htop > /dev/tty0
```

Then the output of htop will be printed directly on screen (hdmi connection)
I would like to run htop as service, but when I do that in a systemd script it says

```
systemd error opening terminal unknown
```

How to solve that?
I tried also

```
cat /dev/null | htop > /dev/tty
```

Same result...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This is a programming question. These commands are running in a bash script.

Comment: As written you are just showing problems running your command. Please show the script and state the exact problem or error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set

```
[Service]
StandardOutput=tty
```

in the `.service` file.  See `systemd.exec(5)` for details.